# Jquery not listening to click

Tags: jquery

This very simple code won't work.

```
<p class="first_name">Kevin</p>

<script language="javascript" src="jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    $(function()){
        $('.first_name').click(function() {
            $('.first_name').hide();
        });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL1b0v9j/)

Comment: You have an extra ) after function()

Comment: that very simple code also throws errors in browser console .... check for errors!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.first_name').click(function() {
            $('.first_name').hide();
        });
```

Please see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/hL1b0v9j/1/

It is working as expected.